# Some text elements have delay when showing browser on angular 6

Tags: angular6

I have angular 6 page with two text line. But when page renders first line is having some delay. Only the second line is showing first. Then after some delay first line is showing.

I have different font-weights for those line. But when I changed them to same font-weight they showing at same time. I want both text lines showing at same time event they have different font-weights.

Comment: It's a font loading issue. Preload your fonts using `<link preload`

Comment: @Kenny you are right. It works can you add this as a answer. So I can accept it.

Comment: @Sanchintha posted as a answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it's a font loading issue. You should preload your font like

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" preload>
```

I would also like you to tell a very interesting css property, maany of developers don't know about this.

If you want to wait for your fonts to gets loaded and also don't want to preload your fonts, You can use `font-display: swap`.

What it does is it 'instructs the browser to use the fallback font to display the text until the custom font has fully downloaded'.

I know this is not related to your question, but it's worth to have a look into it.

More :- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-display/